# HTML/CSS form alignment of radio and checkbox subsequent options with main label

Tags: css, forms, checkbox, radio-button, alignment

I can't figure out why the alignment of radio/checkbox subsequent options (after the first option) is aligning to the left of the page rather than stacking up underneath the first option, with the main label aligned to the left of the options and white space underneath. Any ideas?

See screenshot here: [image]

I can give a `margin-left` on the inputs, but then the first option is indented too far. I just want them to stack up neatly underneath each other.

**CSS**

```css
form.form p label {
    font-size: 120%;
    line-height: 140%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 13px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
    width: 200px;
    color: #333333 !important;
}
form.form input[type = radio], form.form input[type = checkbox] {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -1px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
form.form p label.inline {
    background: 0;
    display: inline;
    float: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
}
```

**EDIT:** This problem is only occurring on the iPad version of my form (desktop version is fine and code is the same, which is what is stumping me the most).

Comment: Sorry. This is the first question I've posted to stackoverflow. Thanks to those who edited.

Comment: Its no problem, I was simply suggesting that the HTML markup would help us provide you with a better answer.